# Prove that if the Hessian of $f$ is positive definite at $a$, then the function attains a minimum at $a$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to prove that if the Hessian $A$ of $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is positive definite at $a$, then the function attains a minimum at $a$.

I can't figure out how to use the definition itself, $x^TAx>0$.  So I'm trying to use the fact that since the Hessian is symmetric, that being positive definite is equivalent to all the eigenvalues being positive, and also using the fact that a symmetric matrix has eigenvectors which form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So basically I'm trying to show that for any vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $Ax$ does not change the sign of any of the components of the vector.  I'm pretty sure this is a valid way to show that curvature is positive in all directions, but I'm not positive.

Anyways since every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as in terms of the orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$.  I have $Ax = \lambda_1(x\bullet b_1)x + ... + \lambda_n(x\bullet b_n)x$.

Can anyone straighten out my understanding of this problem?

**Edit:** This is for $n\geq 2$ and the Hessian invertible.

Comment: Hint: show, based on your reasoning, that there exists $c>0$ such that for all $x$ one has $x^TAx> c\|x\|^2$.

Comment: @JonathanY. I'm having trouble seeing how this shows positive curvature in all directions.

Comment: Well, you need a method of estimating the difference between the values the function evaluates to in a neighborhood of the given point. Do you know any such theorem?

Comment: not off the top of my head no, we've just been using this condition without explanation in a numerical optimization class.

Comment: Let me put it another way: can you estimate the values of a twice-continuously-differentiable function in a neighborhood of a given point, given its gradient and Hessian there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true. The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \|x\|^2$ has Hessian $I$ which is positive definite everywhere, but only $x=0$ is a minimum.

If you assume that $a$ is a stationary point of $f$, and that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable at $a$, then the statement is **locally** true.

Taylor's theorem gives
$f(a+h) = f(a) + \frac{ \partial f(a) }{ \partial x } h + \frac{1}{2} \langle h, \frac{ \partial^2 f(\xi) }{ \partial x^2 } h \rangle$, for some $\xi$ on the line between $a$ and $a+h$.

We have assumed that $a$ is a stationary point, hence $\frac{ \partial f(a) }{ \partial x } = 0$.
Since $\frac{ \partial^2 f(a) }{ \partial x^2 } > 0$, we have $\frac{ \partial^2 f(\xi) }{ \partial x^2 } > 0$ for $\xi$ in some neighborhood $U$ of $a$. Hence for $\xi \in U$, we have $\langle h, \frac{ \partial^2 f(\xi) }{ \partial x^2 } h \rangle \ge 0$. Combining these gives $f(a+h) \ge f(a)$ for all $a+h \in U$. Hence $f(a)$ is a local minimum.

In fact, the above can be tweaked slightly to show that, in fact, $a$ is a **strict** local minimizer:

Let $\phi(x,h) = \langle h, \frac{ \partial^2 f(x) }{ \partial x^2 } h \rangle$, and $\eta(x) = \min_{\|h\| = 1} \phi(x,h)$. A little work shows that $\eta$ is continuous at $x=a$, and $\eta(a) >0$. Hence for some neighborhood $V$ of $a$, and some $\lambda>0$, we have $\eta(x) \ge \lambda > 0$ for all $x \in V$. It follows from this that $\phi(x,h) \ge \lambda \|h\|^2$ for $x \in V$.

Then, for $a+h \in U \cap V$, we have $f(a+h) \ge f(a) + \lambda \|h\|^2$.

Comment: You're right, I guess I should have specified for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Rather, one assumes you'd required that $\nabla f = 0$ at the relevant point.

Comment: Same applies for $n=1$.

Comment: I don't know about other conditions, I'm basing this off of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test#Functions_of_many_variables I guess it says the Hessian must be invertible as well.

Comment: Positive definite implies invertibility. Like @JonathanY. wrote, you need stationarity as well.

Comment: Are you sure?  The wikipedia article doesn't mention it.

Comment: Look at the words 'critical point'.

Comment: oh shoot you're right, ok that makes sense.

Comment: I have added some detail. Taylor's theorem is an **essential** tool for optimization. I prefer the integral form, but it adds clutter.

Comment: Although being less elegant, perhaps using the Peano form of the reminder would be clearer--as it saves us the need to show $Hf(x_0+h)>0$ for sufficiently small $h$.

Comment: @JonathanY.: Also avoids the assumption that $f$ is $C^2$, but you need to show that the 2nd order term dominates the remainder.

Comment: @copper.hat : $\:$ That tweak seems to simple that you should probably do it in your answer. $\hspace{1.11 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Done.

Comment: Oh. $\:$ I thought it was even simpler than that. $\:$ (I thought you could just replace the $\geq$ signs with $>$ and put in "for $h\neq 0$" after the first one.) $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: You could, but it is nice to have explicit bounds.

Comment: @copper.hat. Which result you are using to conclude that given the hypothesis that the Hessian is positive definite at the point a, it will remain positive definite at a close point $\xi$? Thanks.

Comment: @user996159 Continuity of the Hessian.